# Convert decimal hour.minutes to hh:mm tt format and viceverza

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert a decimal value that is stored in hours.minutes (I believe value is stored in hours.hundreds) to a format like hh:mm: tt for example.

- 11.00 to 11:00 AM
- 11.02 to 11:01 AM
- 11.03 to 11:02 AM
- 11.05 to 11:03 AM
- 11.07 to 11:04 AM
- 11.08 to 11:05 AM
- 11.10 to 11:06 AM
- 11.12 to 11:07 AM
- 11.13 to 11:08 AM
- 11.15 to 11:09 AM
- 11.17 to 11:10 AM
- 11.18 to 11:11 AM
- 11.20 to 11:12 AM
- 11.22 to 11:13 AM
- 11.23 to 11:14 AM
- 11.25 to 11:15 AM
- 11.27 to 11:16 AM
- 11.28 to 11:17 AM
- 11.30 to 11:18 AM
- 11.32 to 11:19 AM
- 11.33 to 11:20 AM
- 11.35 to 11:21 AM
- 11.37 to 11:22 AM
- 11.38 to 11:23 AM
- 11.40 to 11:24 AM
- 11.42 to 11:25 AM
- 11.50 to 11:30 AM
- 11.58 to 11:35 AM
- 11.67 to 11:40 AM
- 11.75 to 11:45 AM
- 11.83 to 11:50 AM
- 11.92 to 11:55 AM
- 23.00 to 11:00 PM
- 23.02 to 11:01 PM
- 23.03 to 11:02 PM
- 23.05 to 11:03 PM
- 23.07 to 11:04 PM
- 23.08 to 11:05 PM etc.

and viceverza

- 11:00 PM to 23.00
- 11:01 PM to 23.02 etc.

Comment: You should not be doing this, I think.  Instead, just store your data as a proper date/time type in SQL Server, and then use the database to output it the way you want.

Comment: It's very often that 'someone else did it', especially if taking on data from legacy applications, and even new applications.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do customizations for an ERP, unfortunately the value is stored in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal to Time:

```
timefromparts(floor(x),(x % 1) * 60,0,0,0)
```

You should store the data using the TIME datatype, only for display you might cast it:

```
convert(varchar(7), timefromparts(floor(x),(x % 1) * 60,0,0,0), 100)
```

The TIME back to DECIMAL is simple:

```
cast(datepart(hour,t) + (datepart(minute,t)/60.) as dec(4,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This formular will give an exact match as described.

The strange constant .000147222 is for rounding up instead of truncating:

```
DECLARE @ table(col1 decimal(4,2), col2 time(0))
INSERT @
values
('11.00','11:00 AM'),('11.02','11:01 AM'),('11.03','11:02 AM'),('11.05','11:03 AM'),
('11.07','11:04 AM'),('11.08','11:05 AM'),('11.10','11:06 AM'),('11.12','11:07 AM'),
('11.13','11:08 AM'),('11.15','11:09 AM'),('11.17','11:10 AM'),('11.18','11:11 AM'),
('11.20','11:12 AM'),('11.22','11:13 AM'),('11.23','11:14 AM'),('11.25','11:15 AM'),
('11.27','11:16 AM'),('11.28','11:17 AM'),('11.30','11:18 AM'),('11.32','11:19 AM'),
('11.33','11:20 AM'),('11.35','11:21 AM'),('11.37','11:22 AM'),('11.38','11:23 AM'),
('11.40','11:24 AM'),('11.42','11:25 AM'),('11.50','11:30 AM'),('11.58','11:35 AM'),
('11.67','11:40 AM'),('11.75','11:45 AM'),('11.83','11:50 AM'),('11.92','11:55 AM'),
('23.00','11:00 PM'),('23.02','11:01 PM'),('23.03','11:02 PM'),
('23.05','11:03 PM'),('23.07','11:04 PM'),('23.08','11:05 PM')



SELECT 
  stuff(stuff(convert(varchar(19),
    cast((col1)/24+.000147222 as datetime),0), 1,12,''), 6,0,' ') Calculatedcol2, 
  col2,
  cast(cast(cast(col2 as datetime) as float)*24 as decimal(4,2)) CalculatedCol1,
  col1
FROM @
```

Comment: I think "strange constant" must be equals to 30 seconds. 30 seconds as part of 24 hours is 30/(24 * 60 * 60) == 0.000347222

Answer (score 0):

A little ugly but works in my SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @decimal_time FLOAT 
SET @decimal_time = 23.08
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST( @decimal_time / 24.0 AS DATETIME), 100), 13, 10)

Result->11:04PM

DECLARE @DecTimeStr varchar(8)
SET @DecTimeStr = '11:01 PM'
SELECT ROUND(CAST(CONVERT(DATETIME, @DecTimeStr, 120) AS FLOAT) * 24, 2)

Result->23.02
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
select 
    format(dateadd(minute, cast(((value % 1) * 60 + 0.5) as int), dateadd(hour,  cast(value as int), '1900-01-01')), 'hh:mm tt')
from
    (values
        (11.00), (11.02), (11.03), (11.05), (11.07), (11.08), (11.10), (11.12), (11.13), (11.15),
        (11.17), (11.18), (11.20), (11.22), (11.23), (11.25), (11.27), (11.28), (11.30), (11.32),
        (11.33), (11.35), (11.37), (11.38), (11.40), (11.42), (11.50), (11.58), (11.67), (11.75),
        (11.83), (11.92), (23.00), (23.02), (23.03), (23.05), (23.07), (23.08)) as T(value);

select
    cast(cast(cast(cast(time as datetime) as float) * 24000 as int) / 1000.0 as decimal(4,2))
from
    (values
        ('11:00 AM'), ('11:01 AM'), ('11:02 AM'), ('11:03 AM'), ('11:04 AM'), ('11:05 AM'), ('11:06 AM'), ('11:07 AM'), ('11:08 AM'),
        ('11:09 AM'), ('11:10 AM'), ('11:11 AM'), ('11:12 AM'), ('11:13 AM'), ('11:14 AM'), ('11:15 AM'), ('11:16 AM'), ('11:17 AM'),
        ('11:18 AM'), ('11:19 AM'), ('11:20 AM'), ('11:21 AM'), ('11:22 AM'), ('11:23 AM'), ('11:24 AM'), ('11:25 AM'), ('11:30 AM'),
        ('11:35 AM'), ('11:40 AM'), ('11:45 AM'), ('11:50 AM'), ('11:55 AM'), ('11:00 PM'), ('11:01 PM'), ('11:02 PM'), ('11:03 PM'),
        ('11:04 PM'), ('11:05 PM')) as T(time)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe...

a) From hundreds to clock time (tested):

`SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('11.00', 'HH24.MI'), 'HH:MI AM') FROM DUAL;`

b) From clock time to hundreds should be:

`SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('11:00 PM', 'HH:MI AM'), 'HH.MI') FROM DUAL;`